# date search and textfield format ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, text, format

Here the thing, i'm doing a DATE search in rails using textfield, but when I use date_select instead of text_field_tag the search don't work. There is a function that I have that maybe is getting problems. Here the code.

Controller

```
if self.is_date(params[:s_fec_min])
@items = View_item.all.order("fec_vencimiento ASC").page(params[:page]).per(15).search_fec_min(params[:s_codigo], params[:s_den_cont], params[:s_marca], params[:s_fec_min])


def is_date(temp)
begin
  return true if Date.parse(temp)
    rescue
     return false
  end
end
```

Index.html

```
<%= date_select :s_fec_min, params[:s_fec_min], :include_blank => true %>  
#<%= text_field_tag :s_fec_min, params[:s_fec_min] %>
```

The first one didn't work, the second one works good

View_item

```
def self.search_fec_min(s_codigo, s_den_cont, s_marca, s_fec_min)  
where("codigo ilike :s_c and den_cont ilike :s_d and marca ilike :s_m and fec_vencimiento >= :s_fmin", s_c: "%#{s_codigo}%", s_d: "%#{s_den_cont}%", s_m: "%#{s_marca}%", s_fmin: "#{s_fec_min}")
end
```

I also tried with DateTime in the function but no effect. Can anyone have a suggestion?. Tks

UPDATE
I added # as mencioned but of course that is not the problem, just forgot to comment that line here, in my app is commnet.

Comment: your `date_select` and your `text_field_tag` both use the same name (`:s_fec_min`). This means the params received will contain `params[:s_fec_min]`, but the value will be overwritten by the last input of the form (which is your `text_field_tag`). You can either change the name of one of the input OR comment out one of the two.

Comment: Hello, that is not the problem, I missed to add the # in my comment.I just added to you to understand what line works..

Answer (score 0):

You have same name 's_fec_min' for `text_field_tag` & `date_select` that is creating problem

just comment out `text_field_tag` and check again it should work

```
<%= date_select :s_fec_min, params[:s_fec_min], :include_blank => true %>  
<%#= text_field_tag :s_fec_min, params[:s_fec_min] %>
```

Comment: Tks...but of course I just added the two lines for you to understand the problem...I forgot to add the # in one line. Any suggestion??